# Xdebug trough a nat VM SERVER

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, ssh, server, xdebug

I have a virtual machine running on my system which hosts an apache webserver with a php application I am trying to debug trough xdebug, the guest vm is configured using RedHat virtmanager and is a Hyper-V machine converted in qcow2, the network type of the interface is NAT(default): the current address of the guest is:

```
192.168.122.78
```

I've tried various configurations of xdebug the current one is:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.client_host = 192.168.122.1
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.log=/var/www/clients/client1/web4/web/xdebug.log
xdebug.discover_client_host = false
```

I got the xdebug.client_host IP address from running inside the guest:

```
$ echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{ print $1}'
192.168.122.1
```

I configured the php-xdebug extension ins Vscode with the following:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "hostname": "192.168.122.78", --->ip adress of guest machine
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/clients/client1/web4/web": "${workspaceRoot}"   
              }
 
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

However i get this error

```
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 192.168.122.78:9003
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1301:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1503:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  errno: -99,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '192.168.122.78',
  port: 9003
}
```

As i understood xdebug calls for a connection to a client (my host machine)  and the client listen to this port:
If i try to telnet and check the port for connection trough the ip address of the guest i receive a connection refused error:

```
$ telnet 192.168.122.78 9003                                                                                                                                                                                  
Trying 192.168.122.78...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connessione rifiutata
```

I dont have any iptables rules on the server as i removed them and accepted all incoming and outgoing connections:

```
$ iptables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 329 packets, 28028 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 261 packets, 31104 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

this is the xdebug log of the server:

```
[1366] Log opened at 2021-10-27 13:32:21.938749
[1366] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.122.1:9003.
[1366] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for '192.168.122.1:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[1366] [Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 192.168.122.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
[1366] Log closed at 2021-10-27 13:32:21.940222
```

Obviously enabling
`xdebug.discover_client_host = false`  doesn´t change the situation.

Any idea on whats causing this issue? Any help is appreciated,
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

> "hostname": "192.168.122.78", --->ip adress of guest machine

I think that's your problem. The `hostname` there should be left empty, *or* the IP address of the IP where Xdebug is going to connect **to**, which in your case is `192.168.122.1`.

Comment: Tried both, i don't get errors anymore from xdebug part and even Vscode listens to the port however, still doesn´t work, can't see stack trace or variable values, is this an expected behavior? Application built with yii2 framework.